# CamScanner - how to get image instead of PDF

Tags: document-scanner

I run CamScanner 3.2. In earlier versions, it used to save the image as a JPG (or PNG, don't remember), but with the latest version, it always seems to save as a PDF. I couldn't find any setting to make CamScanner save the scanned thing as a image file. Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

If you view a document, it will be exported as a PDF. Individual pages however are exported as a JPG.

So you must select the document, then select the page, *then* select "Share". If you don't see the "OCR Recognize" button to the left of "Share", you aren't looking at the individual page.